# small balls escape from big ball

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

here is the fiddle http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hKzfl on what i am trying to do. i want to make one ball on the circle that is constant in position i.e., not spinning. the main aim is to escape constant ball from the main ball. if the main ball which is rotating from my fiddle touches any of the constant ball then it should end. one point for each ball escape. i cant position a constant ball on the circle. here is an example of what i like 2 do.here is an example of what i like 2 do. http://www.lessmilk.com/9/

```
<div class="circle">
  <div class="ball_blue"></div>
  <div class="ball_red"></div>
  <div class="ball_green"></div>
  <div class="ball_violet"></div>
</div>

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/**
* Move in a circle without wrapper elements
* Idea by Aryeh Gregor, simplified by Lea Verou
*/

@keyframes rot {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
      translate(-150px)
      rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg)
      translate(-150px) 
      rotate(-360deg);
  }
}

.circle {
  border:1px solid grey;
  position: relative;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  margin:25px auto;
  border-radius:50%;
}

.ball_blue {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  background:blue;
  border-radius:50%;
  font-size: 100px;
  animation: rot 3s infinite linear;
}

.ball_red {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  background:red;
  border-radius:50%;
  /* INITIALLY CENTERED */
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  /* PUSH TO CIRCLE */
  transform: translate(-150px);
  /* PUSH OUT OF CIRCLE */
  margin-left: -20px;
}

.ball_green {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  background:green;
  border-radius:50%;
  /* INITIALLY CENTERED */
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin-top: -150px;
  margin-left: -150px;
  /* PUSH TO CIRCLE */
  transform: translate(-150px);
  /* PUSH OUT OF CIRCLE */
  margin-left: 65px;
}


.ball_violet {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  background:violet;
  border-radius:50%;
  /* INITIALLY CENTERED */
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin-top: -150px;
  margin-left: -150px;
  /* PUSH TO CIRCLE */
  transform: translate(-150px);
  /* PUSH OUT OF CIRCLE */
  margin-left: 215px;
}
```

Comment: Do you really mean "escape" or do you mean "jump over"?

Comment: Jump over like this example- http://www.lessmilk.com/9/

Comment: So you're going to need some fairly sophisticated javascript to have the position of the fixed ball change when the moving ball gets close and passes the fixed ball.

Comment: Yes, when onclick on the fixed ball it can jump from moving ball and if both ball touches then an alert collided is displayed.